# neo4j error: Type mismatch: expected Float or Integer but was Node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the below data set on neo4j

```
create (recipe1:recipe {name: 'recipe-1'})
create (recipe2:recipe {name: 'recipe-2'})
create (recipe3:recipe {name: 'recipe-3'})
create (recipe4:recipe {name: 'recipe-4'})
create (recipe5:recipe {name: 'recipe-5'})
create (recipe6:recipe {name: 'recipe-6'})
create (user1:user {name: 'user-1'})
create (user2:user {name: 'user-2'})
create (user3:user {name: 'user-3'})
create (user4:user {name: 'user-4'})
create
  (user1)-[:LIKES]->(recipe1),
  (user1)-[:LIKES]->(recipe2),
  (user1)-[:LIKES]->(recipe4),
  (user2)-[:LIKES]->(recipe4),
  (user2)-[:LIKES]->(recipe6),
  (user3)-[:LIKES]->(recipe1),
  (user3)-[:LIKES]->(recipe3),
  (user3)-[:LIKES]->(recipe6),
  (user4)-[:LIKES]->(recipe4)
```

and trying to run the below query:

```
match (user4:user {name: 'user-4'})-[LIKES]->recipe<-[:LIKES]-slm-[:LIKES]->recommendations
where not(user4 = slm) and not(user4-recommendations)
return count(*) AS recommendationsWeight, 
recommendations.name AS name
order by recommendationsWeight DESC, name DESC
```

but I am getting the below error:

```
Type mismatch: expected Float or Integer but was Node (line 2, column 32 (offset: 123))
"where not(user4 = slm) and not(user4-recommendations)"
                                ^
```

any idea what I am doing wrong here?

**Update:**

What I want to do here with `not(user4-recommendations)` is to say that any recommendations which user4 has no relationship with. For example, consider this:

```
match (user4:user {name: 'user-4'}), (recipe1:recipe {name: 'recipe-1'})
create (user4)-[:DISLIKES]->(recipe1)
```

So, the result of my recommendation query should not include `recipe1` as user has interacted with it before.

Comment: I think I also have another mistake on my query: `match (user4:user {name: 'user-4'})-[LIKES]` where it should really be: `match (user4:user {name: 'user-4'})-[:LIKES]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo:: `-` instead `=`. And do not forget the parentheses:

```
match (user4:user {name: 'user-4'})-[LIKES]->
      (recipe)
      <-[:LIKES]-(slm)-[:LIKES]->
      (recommendations)
where not(user4 = slm) and not(user4 = recommendations)
return count(*) AS recommendationsWeight, 
       recommendations.name AS name
order by recommendationsWeight DESC, 
         name DESC
```

I think that you're trying to build a recommendatory system. Then, the request will be easier (no checks are not necessary, it works because it is not used a [zero-length path](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#_zero_length_paths)):

```
match (user4:user {name: 'user-4'})
      -[:LIKES]->(recipe)<-[:LIKES]-
      (slm)-[:LIKES]->(recommendations)
where not ( (user4)-[:DISLIKES|LIKES]->(recommendations) )
return recommendations, 
       count(recommendations) as recommendationsWeight  
order by recommendationsWeight desc, 
      recommendations.name asc
```

Comment: `not(user4 = recommendations)` doesn't make sense really as user4 is a user whereas recommendations is a collection of recipes. What I want to say here is: "any recommendations that a user has no relation to".

Comment: Well, I answered the question - "why the error" :) Can you explain more clearly what result you want to get?

Comment: also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643474/neo4j-error-type-mismatch-expected-float-or-integer-but-was-node#comment62768795_37643474

Comment: thx, I think it should also be `(user4:user {name: 'user-4'})-[:LIKES]->` on your query, correct? I messed up on the relationship syntax

Comment: I don't think that covers the case for any recommendation where user4 hasn't interacted with. I think this is what I want: `not((user4)-[]-(recommendations))` which would replace `not(user4-recommendations)`